# 2 different layouts 1 for admin panel and 1 for front website in Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to build 2 different layouts, 1 for my admin panel which will have a sidebar and main area and 1 for my website which will have header, navbar, main area and a footer. I just want 2 layouts, don't want to define layout per page. Is there any logic to do that in Next.JS?

Answer (score 4):

In your `_app.js` you can check which layout should be use by `pageProps` define per page

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const getLayout =
        pageProps.typeLayout == 'admin' ? ((page) => <AdminLayout children={page} />)
        : ((page) => <FrontLayout children={page} />);

    return (
        <>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />, pageProps)}
        </>
    );
};
```

and in per pages, you should return props in `getServerSideProps`

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    return {
            props: { 
                typeLayout : 'admin',
            },
    };
};
```

or you can define layout by router name

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps, router }) => {
    const getLayout =
        router.pathname.includes('/admin') ? ((page) => <AdminLayout children={page} />)
        : ((page) => <FrontLayout children={page} />);

    return (
        <>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />, pageProps)}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works. But there is a problem with this for my project. I have so many admin pages, If I want to do like this I have to write the same code for many pages. So I want to avoid per page solution.

Comment: so i think you should define layout by router name, have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

My main problem is that I have so many admin pages and so many front pages. So, I don't want to have per page solution for this project. So, I think if I could use pathname instead. My admin panel routes starts with '/admin-panel', So I checked for that. The following logic in `_app.js` works for me

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  const adminPanel = router.route.startsWith('/admin-panel') ? true : false
  const getLayout =
    adminPanel ? ((page) => <AdminLayout children={page} />)
      : ((page) => <FrontLayout children={page} />);

  return (
    <>
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />, pageProps)}
    </>
  );
```